# How to use Digital Signature to Sign Unsigned Transaction?

Tags: signature, bitcoinjs, message-signing, signrawtransaction

so I was trying to sign my unsigned transaction:

`010000000194d612f5ec40d483ed82bf346d8f08961d61fdf2d6b9804d7731e608d816e5330000000000ffffffff01204e0000000000001600143b36ddb4d9f75f4010450b25a8952a6725981bfb00000000`

with a digital signature (ECDSA SIGNATURE in hex representation) I created based on this unsigned transaction which is:

`3044022098f9780241fdd9f87a222a85cc65140f61913476c2d3c0f886e328a03f897ea4022089388ea886bb4d2440893665dc54fb7d4a0498766b4752b15415fb18dc38b72a`.

How to serialize these two so that I can use this digital signature to sign the unsigned transaction. Any explanation, example or any package (in Node.js) or otherwise also would be really helpful.

I tried finding examples and test cases and even went through code for bitcoinjs-lib but I've not been able to find a single example of using a digital signature to sign and send a transaction. Most of them try